# Items aren't showing up in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

So, I created a `ListView` and am currently trying to add items once a button is clicked. But, that doesn't seem to be working for me: the items I'm adding (at least that's what I think I'm doing) aren't showing up in the `ListView`. What seems to be the problem here? Any and all help would be appreciated.

Methods

```
private void setListViewItem(string value) {
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(value);
    this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    setListViewItem(textBox1.Text);
}
```

`ListView` properties

```
this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {this.columnHeader1});
this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 87);
this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(277, 91);
this.listView1.TabIndex = 9;
this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add columns to make your data show up since you have `listView1.View` set to `Details`, if you set `listView1.View` to `List`, it will work without having to add columns.

You can check this example [ListView.View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view(v=vs.110).aspx) to see how to add data into a `Detail` view.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to populate the ItemSource. Please check this link, it should help: [ListView, data binding and ItemTemplate](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/)